# Play Framework 2.3 and GAE - Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, playframework, playframework-2.3

Is there any sample application that uses Play Framework 2.3 and Google App Engine?

Comment: What have you found so far? Otherwise it will be closed

Comment: About to try Play 2.3. Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: Here's a github project based on Play and GAE https://github.com/siderakis/playframework-appengine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far I have found this one: https://github.com/siderakis/playframework-appengine

Answer (score -1):

Here is another tutorial with example:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/first-play-framework-gae-siena-application-tutorial-example/

Comment: This only works for Play 1.x, but this is about app engine 2.3 explicitly