# Play 2.3: "activator install gae" not working

Tags: playframework

I'm not new to programming, java, frameworks, etc, and have used the GAE pretty extensively. What I am new to, is using the Play framework, and trying to run it on the GAE.

The documentation on the Play Framework site, at this point, seems very out of date (even the initial tutorial) as to what worked formerly ("play" this and that), and what works now ("activator" this and that). Even the link I found to the standalone Play framework just takes you to the Activator download.

However, the site does make clear, that "activator" works exactly as "play" did, and for the most part, I have found this to be true (substitute "activator" for "play" and you get what you want).

This is unfortunately NOT true of "play install gae". The Play website makes it look very easy, saying "A Play application can very easily be deployed to the GAE. ". Note that this feature, and scala 2.10+ support, is why I decided to give Play a try for my new project.

Here is the Play page that makes it look oh so easy...and yes, I do see 1.2 in the link...I could find no equivalent anywhere for 2.3...and I also found a link that says to modify the app config file with the GAE module, and that it would appear in the "WAR directory" of the project...but there isn't one. I'm assuming that referred to a pre-2.x version of Play as well.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/deployment

Attempting to run "activator install gae" results in the following. I am completely stonewalled by it, and running on the GAE is a dealbreaker unfortunately (unless someone else can recommend a production-ready click-n-deploy option, that has a similar "get off the ground free, auto-scale-via-cloud-model, pay if it starts to see real usage", service, that works easily for Play apps). All of these lines are proceeded by "[error]"

- Not a valid command: install (similar: initialize, inspect, shell)

  Not a valid project ID: install Expected ':' (if selecting a
  configuration) Not a valid key: install (similar: lintian,
  initialize, dist)

  install

Anybody have any wisdom on this at all. Please, no "why are you trying to use the GAE" question/responses unless you can recommend an almost functionally-in-all-regards-identical service. I also don't want to heavily modify the project such that typical play 2.3 features break.

Been working on this for about a day, at this point I'm about ready to say, Play 2.3 + GAE is not a straightforward match.

Comment: For the record, and after a fair amount of research, for now I'm going to go with my own homegrown framework and otherwise just use a vanilla Eclipse GAE project with Scala nature added. This gives me Scala 2.11 and let's me otherwise keep things simple. It didn't take long at all to figure out how to deploy this, the only trick you have to remember is make sure your scala libs are dumped into your web-info lib folder before you deploy or you will get a ton of class not founds, even if everything works properly locally.

If nada else, the past day educated me: GAE + Play 2.3 != "play nice".

Comment: this is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069774/play-framework-2-3-and-gae-google-app-engine

Comment: I saw that, and tried it. The consensus seems to be, it either doesn't work (my experience), or initially works but breaks in expanded use; not ready for prime time. There is also no definitive "answer" (not to mention the first link is dated back to 2011). 

Also, as indicated, I don't want to "adapt" the Play framework. Such "adaptations" tend to lead to more "adaptations". Messy. 

What I am gathering here, is that the deployment data on the Play website/docs is EXTREMELY out of date, and, the Play devs just decided to break basic compatibility with the GAE (or are still working on it).

Comment: @TimConsolazio I think you are mixing Play1 and Play2. Despite the same name they are different frameworks (they are even coded in different languages...) and you can't expect that what works in one will automatically work in the other. Can you provide the links to play 2.3 documentation that you think are outdated?

Comment: Go to the website where you download 2.3, watch the getting started video on that download page, the commands the trainer indicates seem out of date. Then on the same page, search for "Deployment". You will go to a page that describes the GAE.

Answer (score 0):

Going to close out this question; at the time of this article (Play 2.3), the state of the Play framework is not straightforwardly compatible with deployment to the Google Application Engine (the "activator install gae" command, and subsequently related GAE commands, don't work).

Documents from the previous version of Play (1.x), which did say that deployment to the GAE was simple, are mixed in somewhat freely with docs for 2.x, which might give you the impression it can be done in 2.x, but always look carefully at the version you're dealing with (e.g. a link on a 2.3 version page can take you to a doc from 1.x).

Nothing against the Play framework at all, I have heard people in the field talking about it and indicating it's useful. This specific need though (the GAE) doesn't seem ready at this time.